# Cantor Set Looking for what is Not remaining?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation, measurable-sets

I have the Cantor Set parsed out into as follows:
\begin{align}\mathrm{Segment\ 1}&=[0,\frac13],[\frac23,1]\\ S_1&=\frac13\\ \mathrm{Segment\ 2}&= [0,\frac19],[\frac29,\frac13],[\frac23,\frac79],[\frac89,1]\\ S_2&=\frac13+\frac29\end{align}
My question are my $S_n$s what is not remaining? Because I have to construct a series of what is not remaining so is that right because then so far I have the following. \begin{equation}\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{3}(\frac23)^n=\frac13+\frac29+\frac{4}{27}+... \end{equation}

Comment: The Cantor set $C$ is formed by deleting open intervals from the interval $[0, 1]$, so your "segments" of successive approximations to $C$ should be unions of closed intervals. It is not clear what your numbers $S_n$ are intended to be.  Are you trying to calculate the measure of $[0, 1] \setminus C$?

Comment: @RobArthan I am summing up the deleted segments that's why, all the way to infinity.

Comment: I think you mean you are summing the lengths of all the segments that have been deleted at stage $n$ of the construction. If so, your formula is correct. (P.S., and that hat does get all over the place: I thought I'd spilt coffee on my screen $\ddot{\smile}$.)

Comment: @RobArthan Yes the ones that have been deleted or not remaining thanks I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. At each step you're calculating a measure of the complement of the Cantor set (in the unit interval). Since the Cantor set is the subset of $[0,1]$ then $\mu(\mathcal{C})=\mu([0,1])-\mu([0,1]\setminus\mathcal{C})$. Now just observe that at step $n$ you've removed total length of $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{n-1}}{3^n}$ which is geometric series that converges to $1$.

Comment: If it is what you read in the comments it's basically the sum of the deleted segments.